# How to prevent typecheck in StaticAnnotation?

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-macros, typechecking, scala-reflect

I am creating some macro libraries that reads some information from annotation on the `enclosing` method.

```
@info(foo(bar, baz))
def enclosing() = {
  myMacro()
}
```

These information are encoded as `foo(bar, baz)` in a `StaticAnnotation` `@info`.

`foo(bar, baz)` contains information `myMacro` need, however, `foo(bar, baz)` is not able to type-check at the position `@info`, and cause compiler error when type-checking `foo(bar, baz)`.

I wonder if I can create a macro `dontTypecheck` that prevent `foo(bar, baz)` being type checked. So that I can create something like:

```
@info(dontTypecheck {
  foo(bar, baz)
})
def enclosing() = {
  myMacro()
}
```

The `dontTypecheck` macro should produce a `Tree` that contains untype-checked `foo(bar, baz)`.

How to create the `dontTypecheck` macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one idea is use another annotation save info

```
class Info[T](t: T) extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation {
}

class AnnInfo extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro AnnInfImpl.impl
}

trait AnnotationUtils {
  val c: scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

  import c.universe._

  final def getAnnotation(x: MemberDef) = x.mods.annotations


}

class AnnInfImpl(val c: blackbox.Context) extends AnnotationUtils {

  import c.universe._
  // edit 1 
  def impl(annottees: Tree*): Tree = {
    annottees.head match {
      case x: DefDef =>
        // collect value from `@Info(value)`
        val info: List[Tree] = getAnnotation(x).collect { case q"new $name ($value)" => value }
        val newBody  =
          q"""
              {
                val info = ${info.map(e => show(e))}
                println(info)// just print it
                ${x.rhs}
              }"""
        DefDef(
          mods = Modifiers(), //dropMods
          name = x.name,
          tparams = x.tparams,
          vparamss = x.vparamss,
          tpt = x.tpt,
          rhs = newBody
        )
    }
  }
}
```

// test

```
class AnnInfoTest {
  val a = 1
  val b = 2

  def f(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b


  @Info(f(a, b))
  @AnnInfo
  def e = ???
}
```

if you call `e` will print `List(f(a, b))`

Comment: Does it work if you delete `def f(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b`?

Comment: It compiles because the macro annotation `@AnnInfo` deleted `@Info(f(a, b))`. How can I recall the `@Info` in a macro inside `e` after `@Info` is deleted?

Comment: see edit 1 ; how to use `value`( extract from `@Info(value)`)   inside `e` ; but i am not sure it is you want ?

Comment: I think the problem is how to pass an untyped tree to a typed def macro...

Comment: sorry, i have not idea :(

Comment: I think your solution is fine. I guess explicitly setting type on a `Tree` would prevent its children being type-checked. So I guess your solution works if replacing `show(e)` to something like `e.setSymbol(xxx); q"myMacro($e)"` or `e.tpe = xxx; q"myMacro($e)"`